# PHP регулярное выражение помогите довершить

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, уважаемые разработчики, помогите дописать регулярное выражение. Вопрос упрощенный: есть такая строка с тегами :

```
aaaa<c>bbbb</c>dddd<c>eeee</c>ffff
```

необходимо чтобы регулярное выражение удалило все что внутри тегов `<c>` (тегов `<c>` может быть любое кол-во), результат должен быть такой:

```
aaaa dddd ffff
```

Делаю так  `preg_replace('~<c>.*</c>~',' ',$txt)`

Справедливо получаю:

```
aaaa ffff
```

Я предполагаю нужно поправить `.*` и в нем указать `.*(кроме<c>)` как это сделать не знаю Выручите буду очень благодарен.
Вот ссылка на код: https://regex101.com/r/kR0tO2/38

Answer (score 1):

```
$txt = 'aaaa<c>bbbb</c>dddd<c>eeee</c>ffff';

echo preg_replace('~<c>(.*?)</c>~',' ',$txt);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

> **Пример с учётом вложенности** :

```
$str = '
    <c><c><c>bbbb</c></c></c>
    ffff
    <c><p><c><c>bbbb</c></c></p></c> 
    aaaa
    <c>bbbb</c>
    dddd
    <p><c>eeee</c>оставить подстроку</p>
    ffff
';

echo preg_replace('~<c>(<.>)?(?(1).+?</c>).+?(</c>)?(?2)++~', '', $str);
```

> Исходный код:

```
ffff

aaaa

dddd
<p>оставить подстроку</p>
ffff
```

[**Смотреть демо**](https://regex101.com/r/oTiXVy/1)

Comment: Благодарю, только если строка будет такой <c><p>текст</p></c> код остановится на внутреннем теге <p>.

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов ну вы ведь про вложенность ничего не упоминали в первом посту... В таком случае такая глубина тоже не пройдёт: `<c><p><c>bbbb</c></p></c>`

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов обновил ответ.